# How do I encrypt multiple Web.config-sections at once with aspnet_regiis.exe -pef?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

By running:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Site
```

I can encrypt my connection strings. However, I'd like to encrypt another section as well at the same time. Are there any way in which I can give multiple arguments to `-pef`?

Something like:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings,applicationSettings/Project" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Site
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully used aspnet_regiis to encrypt (and decrypt) two sections, connectionStrings and appSettings, by executing aspnet_regiis twice in a DOS .bat file.  Looks like you have to execute aspnet_regiis once for each section you want to encrypt (and decrypt).